# Trigger does not update

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I have tables `ILIST_TABLE` and `ITEM_TABLE`. I update `ITEM_TABLE` from `ILIST_TABLE` using this trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER UPDATE_LIST_NAMEIN_ITEM_TABLE
AFTER UPDATE ON ILIST_TABLE FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE ITEM_TABLE
    SET ITEM_ILIST_NAME=NEW.ILISTNAME
    WHERE ITEM_ILIST_NAME = OLD.ILISTNAME;
END;
```

But this not triggering the update, showing:

> "Data could not be updated"

What am I doing wrong? My SQLite version supports triggers.

Comment: I made a simple test database, created a trigger with your CREATE TRIGGER statement then checked whether updating ILIST_TABLE triggers an update in ITEM_TABLE or not. It worked! So as far as I can tell your CREATE TRIGGER statement is correct. Could you show us your CREATE TABLE statements?